# Designated initializer missing a super call to designated initializer of the super class

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

my code is here:

```
(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LSCouponADView" owner:Nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
if (self) {

}

    return self;
}
```

Then xcode has warning

> Designated initializer missing a super call to designated initializer
>   of the super class

when I building it.

Comment: What is the parent class of this class?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this line in this method.

```
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if(self) {

}
return self;
```

From [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MultipleInitializers.html).

**The Designated Initializer**

> > The initializer of a class that takes the full complement of initialization parameters is usually the designated initializer. The designated initializer of a subclass must invoke the designated initializer of its superclass by sending a message to super. The convenience (or secondary) initializers—which can include init—do not call super. Instead they call (through a message to self) the initializer in the series with the next most parameters, supplying a default value for the parameter not passed into it. The final initializer in this series is the designated initializer.

Answer (score 2):

you should make your class some thing like this:

Run tIme init:>

```
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if(!self){
            return nil;
        }

        NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
        NSArray *views = [mainBundle loadNibNamed:@"LSCouponADView" 
                                            owner:nil 
                                          options:nil];
//above nib name should not be hard coded, it should be like this:
//NSArray *views = [mainBundle loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) 
                                                owner:nil 
                                              options:nil];
        [self addSubview:views[0]];

    return self;
    }
```

You should also override for xib initialization:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
    {
        self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
        if(!self){
            return nil;
        }

        NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
        NSArray *views = [mainBundle loadNibNamed:@"LSCouponADView" 
                                                owner:nil 
                                              options:nil];
        [self addSubview:views[0]];

    return self;
    }
```

over all you can make a common method for loading from nib.

Comment: I do it with your idea like this      -(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        UIView *view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LSCouponADView" owner:Nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetHeight(frame));;
        [self addSubview:view];
        
    }
    
    return self;
}

Comment: @waterKnight upvote/acceptance will be motivating :)